# How to login using ajax in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

Is there a way to login using ajax, instead of the default automagical method?

Comment: Make an AJAX call to the action of your login form?

Comment: @Problematic The action for the login form only shows the login form. To actually login a user in symfony 2, you have to submit that form to the login_check route, as specified in both routing.yml and security.yml. Then you get redirected to target or again to the login form if an error ocurred, which is not what one would want for an ajax request. A response in json format would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it work by creating a LoginListener

PS: If someone wants to explain how to do that, I will mark that as the correct answer.

Comment: Mind sharing your LoginListener?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create action ajaxLoginCheckAction() in Controller with route in security zone (for example with route "/admin/ajax_login_check") - for answers you questions about the user
2. Send data to login_check
3. Get data from ajaxLoginCheckAction()

That's all. There is no need to use LoginListener